# assigning multiple structures to an array of structures in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, struct

I have a function `newPartical` that randomizes a structure:

```
function partical = newPartical(b)
   partical.a = rand;
   partical.b = b;
end
```

I want to make an array of structures, and I want each structure in the array to be randomized. can I do this without a for loop?

Comment: Can you explain further? Give a small example with input and output

Comment: How do you plan to use `newPartical` in that `no-loop` code? Maybe you can show us a pseudo-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use iterative functions like `arrayfun` and `cellfun`. These take a function itself as input (via a function handle) and a range of values for each input of the passed function. The output is an array or cell array, where each entry is a single result of the function.

```
particleHandle = @particle;
c = arrayfun ( particleHandle , 1:100 );
```

In this case, `c is a 1x100 struct array with fields: a b`

Sample results I obtained include:

```
c(1).a = 0.5496
c(1).b = 1

c(2).a = 0.9575
c(2).b = 2

c(3).a = 0.9649
c(3).b = 3
```

Depending on what you are doing, this may or may not provide significant improvements in speed. For instance, running these two operations:

```
timeStartArrayFun = tic;
c = arrayfun ( particleHandle , 1:1000 );
timeStopArrayFun = toc ( timeStart );

timeStartFor = tic;
for ( ii = 1 : 1000 )
  d ( ii ) = particle ( ii );
end
timeStopFor = toc ( timeStartFor );
```

The results are `timeStartArrayFun == 0.0201` and `timeStartFor == 0.2090`. You obtain an ~10X speed increase...not bad at all.